# App with Apple Watch rejected because app did not install on the Apple Watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch, submission

I got rejected from Apple Review Team 2 times (It take about 20 days).
Reason

> 2.2 - Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected Thank you for resubmitting your app for review.
>
> 2.2 Details
>
> In continuing our review, we discovered that your watch app did not
>   install on the Apple Watch after the app was installed on iPhone 6
>   running iOS 8 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> Next Steps
>
> It would be appropriate to revise your app to ensure that the user is
>   able to access this feature.

**My Question** is how we submit App with apple watch app without rejected with install problem.

From rejected information that I got.

- 1 st submission Rejected because I set Build Active Architecture only to YES.
- 2 nd submission Rejected (Again) with feedback "app did not install on the Apple Watch after the app was installed on iPhone 6 running iOS 8 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks."

  I have been test with TestFlight it also installed successful with my iPhone6+ and Apple Watch.

I don't know next step what should I do to fixed this issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to dispute it.  I would tell them that it installs just fine with test flight and on a physical device.  Click on your rejected app and click on `Resolution Center`.

[image]

You can also send them screenshots.  Take some of the physical device.  Hell... send them real photographs.

I disputed a rejection on an app update and it was accepted a few days later.

I doubt this is an issue but make sure you're signing with proper certificates and profiles as well... but let them know that they're most likely at fault (and that their whole system is stupid.)

They probably couldn't install the app on their devices because they have all of their "smart" people on their "change spotify" project.